# How can I trigger the line notification function after the function that asks customer to reply their problems to Linebot in the GoogleAppsScript?

Tags: google-apps-script

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ln3YHj6E_3yA9p-A1fpXvOVSNQaztAYF?usp=sharingLineBot will ask question in Line, and Google apps script will receive the results in GoogleSheets, I want to add a function that connect LineNotification, how can I use the lineNotification function after the linebot function finish asking questions in Line???

```
how can I get this done? It seems not so hard but I have  poor coding abilities. PLEASE give me some advise !!! I'll be grateful for your recommendation!!!
```

Comment: Publish a web-app. Receive the webhook via `doPost()`

Comment: How can I ''Receive the webhook via doPost()''? I have another two functions for sending notification via LineNotification，what should I do to the webhook URL ?After linebot finishes asking questions, will it pass something through a parameter or somthing else within the webhook?  I can not figure it out QQ

Comment: [Edit] your question to provide relevant documentation you're referring to and show relevant code snippets.

Comment: I add it on the drive ,please take a look!